# Makefile で実行時にコマンド結果が空かどうか判定したい

Tags: shellscript, makefile

AWS の cli を叩いて、リソースがない場合に作成みたいなことを Makefile の中でやりたいです

シェル変数でも Makefile の変数でもいいのですが
以下のようなテストコマンドをいろいろかいてみたんですがどうやっても空文字にマッチするIF文に入ってくれません

1. シェル変数を使う場合

```
test1:
    export A=1
    echo $A
```

エクスポートしても別の行でとり出せない

```
#make test1
export A=1
echo
```

2. eval のテスト

```
test2:
    $(eval A := 1)
    echo $(A)
ifeq (A, "")
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)
```

これは正常

```
#make test2
echo 1
1
echo 1
1
```

3〜5. 実際に判定してほしいコマンド （違いは ifeq 文のみです)

```
test3:
    $(eval A := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id')))
    echo $(A)
ifeq (A, "")
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)

test4:
    $(eval A := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id')))
    echo $(A)
ifeq ("A", "")
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)

test5:
    $(eval A := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id')))
    echo $(A)
ifeq ($(A), "")
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)
```

どれも api-gateway が定義されてない場合空文字になって
最後に 2 になってほしいのにならない

```
#make test3
echo

echo

#make test4
echo

echo

#make test5
echo

echo
```

どうすればコマンド結果が空かどうかを判定できるでしょうか

もっと根本的に Makefile 内で
aws cli の結果によってリソースを作成するという簡単な方法があったりするでしょうか

make のバージョンは以下です

```
# make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

参考： http://quruli.ivory.ne.jp/document/make_3.79.1/make-jp_6.html#Conditionals

#### 追記：

コメントで教えていただいたリンク先を参照して

```
test6:
    $(eval A := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id'))
    echo $(A)
ifeq ($(A),)
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)
```

という書き方を試したところ

```
# make test6
echo

echo 2
2
```

と IF に入ってくれたのですが

逆に空文字以外でも必ず IF 文にマッチしてしまいます

```
test7:
    $(eval A := 1)
    echo $(A)
ifeq ($(A),)
    $(eval A := 2)
endif
    echo $(A)
```

```
#make test7
echo 1
1
echo 2
2
```

どこか書き方がまずいのでしょうか

Comment: 参考までに、「シェル変数を使う場合」、Makefile では一行づつ別個に処理されます。つまり、シェル変数の有効範囲(extent)は行単位になります。なので、行末にバックスラッシュ(`\ `)を置くなどして継続行にする必要があります。`test1:\n\texport A=1; \ \n\techo $$A` (`\n`はnewline, `\t` は TAB)

Comment: [Makefile set if variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38832692)

Comment: > Makefile では一行づつ別個に処理　リソースIDを取得⇒なければ作成⇒そのリソースIDを使うコマンドをいくつか実行　というコードをかきたいのですべてを１行でかくのは難しいです。リンク先の件追記したのですがうまくいかないです

Comment: AWS については詳しくないですが、結果が空ならコマンドのステータスコードを調べてみるのも一つの方法ではないでしょうか？

Comment: 他のリソースだとそれもできるんですが、apigatewayは同じ名前のリソースが作れてしまうので先に有無を調べるしかないです。コマンド自体は一覧 json 取得⇒jq にパイプで渡して検索なのでどっちもエラーにはならないです。jq じゃなく grep にかえるとか代替方法はいくらでもありそうですが、ただこんな単純なことができないわけないと思うのに数時間かかってもどうしてもうまくいかなくて相談した次第です

Comment: `ifeq` ディレクティブは Makefile が読み込まれる時点で評価されますので、`ifeq ($(A),)` は常に真(True)になってしまいます(変数 A は未定義)。また、`$(eval A := 1)` は `test7` ルールが実行される時点で評価されます。

Comment: そうだったんですね。Makefile でリソース作成⇒そのリソースを Makefile 変数に取得というのは根本的にできないということですか…。１行１行状態を持たないコマンド判定を繰り返すしかないのですね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントにも書きましたが、`ifeq` ディレクティブが Makefile の読み込み時に評価されてしまう事が原因です。

解決策の一つとして、[target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) を使う方法が考えられます。

```makefile
test6: \
    _ := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id')
test6: A := $(if $(_),$(_),2)

test6:
    echo $(A)
```

ただし、この場合は変数を global scope で定義しているので、他の recipe を実行する場合でも `aws apigateway ...` コマンドが常に実行される事になります。`define` ディレクティブで別個に定義しておいて、recipe の実行時に `call` する方が良いかもしれません。

と、書いておいて気が付いたのですが、以下の様にできますね。

```
test6:
    $(eval _ := $(shell aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | select(.name=="test") | .id' 2> /dev/null))
    $(eval A := $(if $(_),$(_),2))
    echo $(A)
```

Comment: ワンライナーの if 文は動的に判定してくれるのですね。使ってみたら分岐できました。複数行のかけないのは少し不便ですが…

Comment: 例えば define 〜 endef で function_if と function_else を定義しておいて、`$(call $(if $(_),function_if,function_else))` などとすると良いかも知れません。

Answer (score 0):

`ifreq` で変数が空文字列かどうかチェックするには、以下のいずれかのように書かないと駄目ですね。

```
ifeq ($(A), )
...
endif
```

```
EMPTY=
ifeq ($(A), $(EMPTY))
...
endif
```

さて、自分だったらどうするかですが、こんな感じになりました。`Makefile` 中でもう一回 `make` を呼んでみました。AWS のリソースではなくファイルを使い、なければ作っています。

```
EMPTY:=
A:=$(shell ls foo)

.PHONY: default
default: target

.PHONY: target-pre
target-pre:
    echo $@
ifeq ($(A), $(EMPTY))
    touch foo
endif

.PHONY: target
target: target-pre
    echo $@
    $(MAKE) target-do

.PHONY: target-do
target-do:
    echo $@
    ls -l foo

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f foo
```